# Is there a way to customize pandas.DataFrame.head()?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the following code snippet and output:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_1': list(range(100)), 'col_2': [list(range(20))]*100})
df.head()
```

[image: table with 4 rows and col_2 being cut off at 13]

is there a way I can customize the output of `df.head()` to have more rows, change the truncation of columns, etc.?

Comment: One should always read [the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html) before asking

Comment: I would make the argument that If you sat down and read the docs you would know everything, it would just take forever. I was surprised this question didn't exist on stack exchange, so I decided to ask it. I actually learned a thing or two as well

Comment: I'm not advocating to read the full thing in one sit (which some people do, and learn a lot). But your specific question might not have been asked before because it is evident in the documentation... in fact it is _the only_ parameter that this function takes. I am a big fanatic of SO, here I learned the little coding I know, but questions that can be answered from official sources are not relevant here. --In other words, you want others to read the docs for you---

Comment: that's completely fair, and I see where you're coming from. I think what makes this question valid is that I didn't want to just change the number of rows, but also `change the truncation of columns, etc.`, which actually requires different approaches. The question was more so "how do a customize the total output of head()", not just "how do I change the number of rows on head". Therefore, I personally think this question has merit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

```
df.head(xxx)
```

xxx = number of rows

You can change other parameters as well with:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize virtually everything with `pd.options.display`. You set the general format with:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_columns = 50  # None -> No Restrictions
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 100
pd.options.display.precision = 3

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col_1': list(range(100)), 'col_2': [list(range(20))]*100, 'col_3': [0.12345]*100})
```

then the number of rows with:

```
df.head(40)
```

[image: sample output]